# What should the inlet to throat area ratio be for a CD rocket nozzle on an aircraft flying at Mach 10?

Tags: engine-design, hypersonic, rocket

I am analysing a rocket CD (convergent-divergent) nozzle at a altitude of 15,000m. I am stuck on how to calculate the areas so that at the throat of the nozzle Mach number equals to one. The atmospheric parameters at 15,000m I have taken to be:

- temperature=216.7k,
- P=12,110pa and
- speed of sound to be 295.1m/s.

The weight of the hypersonic plane being 164kg, fuel used is hydrogen so gamma=1.4 and R=4.124KJ/kg.k. For the total temperature at the inlet I have to be 2527.039K and assumed the pressure to be 1000kpa.

I want the aircraft to fly at Mach 10. I am really struggling on how to get the inlet area to throat area ratio.

[image]

Comment: Is this a rocket or a Ramjet? Drawing and description feels like a ramjet, but you keep saying rocket.

Comment: @federico it is a rocket

Comment: so what are the combustion chamber conditions M1 P1 T1, etc?